# Django import-export buttons DO NOT appear in admin screen

Tags: django, button, import

I followed the django import-export manual but the Import Export buttons do not appear in my admin screen.

This is what I have in my admin.py. Is there anything else I need to do? I have added import-export to my settings.py.

```
from django.contrib import admin
from costtool import models as m
from costtool.models import UserProfile, Prices
from import_export import resources
from import_export.admin import ImportExportModelAdmin, ImportMixin

class PriceResource(resources.ModelResource):
    class Meta:
        model = Prices

class PriceAdmin(ImportExportModelAdmin):
    resource_class = PriceResource
    pass

admin.site.register(UserProfile)
admin.site.register(Prices)
```

Answer (score 6):

Just tell the admin what `ModelAdmin` to use:

```
admin.site.register(Prices, PriceAdmin)
```

You can check Django's [ModelAdmin doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) and try to use the new [register decorator](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#the-register-decorator) if you're using Django 1.7